# How to make a scrollable element draggable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I am having problems trying to make some of my scrollable elements draggable.

I'm using jquery ui, but basically I need the scrollbar to not interfere with the drag events.

See this js fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/eCbSp/

In firefox dragging down on the scrollbar causes the box to move, in chrome / ie the cursor becomes stuck to the box after trying to scroll with the mouse.

Does anyone know if what I'm trying to do is possible?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery drag/scrolling/overflow issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307161/jquery-drag-scrolling-overflow-issue)

Comment: This might help you.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300765/how-to-disable-draggable-div-when-scroll-bar-is-focused-on-in-jquery][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300765/how-to-disable-draggable-div-when-scroll-bar-is-focused-on-in-jquery

Comment: Problem is, chrome does not fire mouseup on scrollbars. See: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=31264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did was place a div inside of your scroll div and set its width to 98% of its parents width. I created it so it could be used as a handle, which means that when a user clicks that element it will actually move your draggable.  Hope this works...worked fine is jsfiddle but didnt try it cross browser, it should work tho =)

```
<div class="valign_outer container">
    <div class="myhandle" style="width:98%; height:100%;">
    <div class="valign_inner">
        <p>How much content is in here?</p>
        <p>Lots</p>
        <p>And Lots</p>
        <p>And Lots</p>
        <p>And Lots</p>
        <p>And Lots</p>
        <p>And Lots</p>
        <p>And Lots</p>
        <p>And Lots</p>
        <p>And Lots</p>
        <p>And Lots</p>
        <p>And Lots</p>
        <p>And Lots</p>
        <p>And Lots</p>
        <p>And Lots</p>
        <p>I am going to be bigger than min height!</p>
    </div>
</div>


var dragOpts = {
    handle: '.myhandle'

}
$('.container').draggable(dragOpts );
```

[Here is a sample of it working](http://jsfiddle.net/eCbSp/1/)